# In R2\(axis X)the two nullhomotopic functions are not homotopic

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I want to prove that in space R2\X  the two functions f&g are not homotopic if we define g(x)=c1& f(x)=c2
c1 and c2 are two points one of the above axis X and the othe one is under it

Comment: What is $X$? What are $c_1$ and $c_2$?

Comment: Axis X, c1 and c2 are two points one of them under axis x and the other one is above it

Comment: What is the domain of $f$ and $g$?

Comment: I don't have that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix a point $p$ in the domain of $f$ and $g$ and suppose there is a homotopy $H \colon D \times I \to \mathbb{R}^2 - X $ between $f$ and $g$.  Then $H$ restricted to $\{p\} \times I $ is a path between $c_1$ and $c_2$, which is impossible since they lie in different path components of $\mathbb{R}^2 - X$.